# How to launch an EFS in the default VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to launch an EFS file system in my default VPC. I am able to create the EFS but not able to mount the target in all subnets. In `subnet_id` I not sure how to pass the value of all the subnet ids of default VPC. Below is my Terraform code:

$ cat ec2.tf

```
provider "aws" {
 [enter image description here][1]region  = "ap-south-1"
 profile = "saumikhp"
}


data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids
  id       = each.value
}


resource "aws_key_pair" "key" {
  key_name   = "mykey12345"
  public_key = file("mykey12345.pub")
}

resource "aws_security_group" "web-sg" {
  name        = "web-sg"
  description = "Allow port 22 and 80"
  vpc_id      = "vpc-18819d70"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 2049
    to_port     = 2049
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "web-sg"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  ami             = "ami-0447a12f28fddb066"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  key_name        = "mykey12345"
  security_groups = ["web-sg"]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("mykey12345")
    host        = aws_instance.myinstance.public_ip
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install httpd php git -y",
      "sudo systemctl restart httpd",
      "sudo systemctl enable httpd",
    ]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "SaumikOS"
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
   creation_token = "efs"
   performance_mode = "generalPurpose"
   throughput_mode = "bursting"
   encrypted = "true"
 tags = {
     Name = "EfsExample"
   }
 }

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.myinstance,
  ]
  for_each        = data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids
  subnet_id = each.value
  file_system_id  = "aws_efs_file_system.efs.id"
  security_groups = ["aws_security_group.web-sg.id"]
}
```

[Error after running terraform apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoQ7e.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the subnets from the default VPC by using a combination of the [`aws_vpc`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html) and [`aws_subnet_ids` data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html).

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}
```

You can then create an EFS mount target in each of the subnets by looping over these (each mount target only takes a single `subnet_id`):

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {
  for_each        = data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
  subnet_id       = each.value
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.web-sg.id]
}
```

Comment: created a vars.tf file with the content,

`variable "vpc_id" {}`
And updated the main.tf as per your instruction. Now I am getting this error.
---------
Error: ValidationException:
 status code: 400, request id: 0e2c0f2b-1c18-434a-b133-cb2c8b34e588

  on ec2.tf line 90, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt":
  90: resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs-mt" {

Comment: You should edit that into your question if it is still related to the initial question. Comments don't allow formatting and are limited in characters so make it impossible to properly read an error. Also they're not meant to be kept around indefinitely so anything useful you can add to debugging the question should be in the question body itself.

Comment: Is the security group also in the default VPC? It's hard to tell when you've hardcoded that VPC ID but then use a variable for the VPC ID for the subnets data source. I'd recommend switching to using a data source to get your VPC ID (either using the default selector as suggested in my answer or specifying a filter that will give you another VPC such as by tags) and avoiding passing arbitrary IDs around.

Comment: If possible please give me the complete terraform code. I am a beginner and it's difficult for me to find the actual error. Thank you so much for helping me until now.

Comment: At this point your question is asking a bunch of different things, some of them very basic. You should consider reworking your question so that it is asking a single question only and shows as much working as possible with any errors directly in line as text rather than as images. You might find it helpful to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question so that it fits the guidelines.